# The best naming conventions for HTML/CSS in present?

Tags: html, css, naming-conventions

I'm interested in: what is **the best naming conventions for HTML/CSS in present**? 
How to call classes in large companies? 
Do you have any documentation? Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably too opinion based for Stack Overflow - the answer depends entirely on what each particular person prefers, and there's no objective right answer. Consider reframing the question about maintainability perhaps, which is more objective and suitable for the site.

Comment: [ask] | [mcve] | http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BEM**'s `block__element_modifier` is quite common and handy for large projects.

You can read more about it on official site:
https://en.bem.info/methodology/

Here's a direct link to the naming conventions docs:
https://en.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/#modifier-name